# Override inline style height auto

Tags: html, css

```
<li style="height: auto;">
                <a >Test</a>
            </li>
```

I have html block as above. The problem here is that, jquery is injecting an inline css as `style="height: auto;"` to *li* element which is distorting the current makeup. How is it possible to overrride height: auto ? I tried `height: 100%;` doesn't work.

Comment: override how? with what? `auto` is the default value

Comment: use !important for your style.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have no control over the inline styles, you can override them by adding `!important` to styles in a stylesheet:

```css
li {
  height: 100px !important;
  background: lightblue !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="height: auto; background: green">
    <a>Test 1</a>
  </li>
  <li style="height: auto; background: green">
    <a>Test 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Upboat as this is one of the only valid uses of `!important` in a web stylesheet IMO. (Dear SO, there are times where I *do* need to comment on my upboats... times like when the unorthodox solution is actually the only one.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do with this but have you tried `height:inherit` or `height:initial` ?

Comment: `height: initial` is the same thing as `height: auto`.

Answer (score 0):

It simple, just set !important to the rule

```
li{
height: 100% !important;
}
```